# How to automatically add times in a date range into a list in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to create a plugin which had a QtComboBox to select from a set of times. I want all the times 7 days before and 7 days after, in 15 minute intervals, to be listed.

Is there a neat way to do this in python without case checking for number of days in months, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

From the `numpy` docs on `datetimes`
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html

```
import numpy as np
np.arange('2005-02', '2005-03', dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

In your case, you would need to change the intervals
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-units

```
dt = np.datetime64('2015-03-06T00:00')
td = np.timedelta64(7, 'D')
np.arange(dt - td, dt + td, dtype='datetime64[15m]')
```